# Initializing 2D lists in Python: How to make deep copies of each row?

Tags: python

Let's say I want to initialize a 2D Python list with all 0's, I'd do something like:

```
test = [[0.0] * 10] * 10
```

Then I start modifying values in the first list...

```
test[0][0] = 1.0
```

But that affects the first item of ALL lists for some reason:

```
print test

[[1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
```

What's going on with that? Why is it making a deep copy of the inner list, but a shallow copy of the outer list?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Doing  `[[0.0] * 10] * 10`actually creates multiple copies of the same list so modifying one will affect all of them:

```
>>> test = [[0.0] * 10] * 10
>>> [id(x) for x in test]     #see all IDs are same
[3065020524L, 3065020524L, 3065020524L, 3065020524L, 3065020524L, 3065020524L, 3065020524L, 3065020524L, 3065020524L, 3065020524L]
```

Try this:

```
>>> test = [[0.0]*10 for _ in xrange(10)]
>>> test[0][0] = 1.0
>>> test
[[1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
```

Integers/floats are immutable, while lists are mutable:

```
>>> x = y = []
>>> x is y       # Both point to the same object
True 
>>> x.append(1)  # list.extend modifies a list in-place
>>> x,y          # both references to [] can see the modification
([1], [1])
>>> x = y = 1
>>> x is y      #both points to the same object
True
>>> x+=1        # only x gets modified, it now points to a new object 2
>>> x,y         # y still points to the same object 1
(2, 1)
```

Comment: How strange! I don't understand *why* it would make deep copies of the inner list (`[0.0] * 10`), but shallow copies of the outer list (`([0.0] * 10) * 10`)

Comment: `[0.0] * 10`  creates `[0.0, 0.0,...]`. integers and floats are immutable in python so even though all of the items of this list point to the same object 0.0 but modifying one won't affect others as they are immutable. On the other hand lists are mutable, modifying one copy affects all other references as well.

Answer (score 3):

The list `test` contains multiple iterations of the *same* list, hence a change in one (as you are making by reassigning the first element of `test[0]`) is reflected in all the others. Try this instead:

```
[[0.0]*10 for _ in xrange(10)]  # or `range` in Python 3.x
```

Of course, you wouldn't need to worry about this if all you had was `[0.0] * 10`, since this creates a list of ints, none of which can ever mutate. Lists, on the other hand, are indeed mutable.